# Passing a value from Netezza back to SAS using a macro variable

Tags: sql, sas, netezza, sas-macro

we're using SAS 7.13 HF1 (7.100.3.5419) (64-bit)

I'm currently looking at a post that shows how to pass a value from SAS to a database that you're connecting in to. Here is the example below. You can see they take the Macro variable StartDate and pass it into Teradata to be used in the query.

```
%let StartDate = 2016/01/01;

proc sql;
   connect to teradata 
    (BULKLOAD=YES MODE=TERADATA user=&user. Password=&passwd.);

   CREATE TABLE WorkTest.test AS
   select * from connection to teradata
   ( 
        SELECT 
            TOP 10 *      
        FROM SomeCalendarData
        WHERE SomeDate = %bquote('&StartDate.');
   ); 
quit;
```

I want to go the other way.

How can I read a value from a similar query, only my DB is Netezza, and somehow pass it to a macro variable in SAS?

Thanks!

Comment: SAS just published a post on this topic here: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/Reading-Data-from-a-Database-into-a-SAS-Macro-Variable-is-EASY/ta-p/503137

Comment: To be clear, SAS does not pass the macro variable into Teradata.  SAS `connection to` sends a (**dbms-query**) to Teradata.  The query in this case is dynamically generated, in so far as requiring a macro variable to be resolved first.  A subtle but important difference.

Comment: Cool. What functions can I use to limit the output to just he first row? It doesn't like "limit 1" or max() or "group by". It also doesn't like trim(). What does work?

Answer (score 2):

You would use the

```
SELECT <expression> INTO :<macro_var>'
```

statement. This is available in the PROC SQL query but not in the pass-through code, so it would look something like

```
proc sql;
   connect to teradata 
    (BULKLOAD=YES MODE=TERADATA user=&user. Password=&passwd.);

   select somedate into :my_macro_var from connection to teradata
   ( 
        SELECT somedate      
        FROM SomeCalendarData
        WHERE id = 101;
   ); 
quit;
```

See the docs here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/63043/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1tupenuhmu1j0n19d3curl9igt4.htm

Comment: Cool. What functions can I use to limit the output to just he first row? It doesn't like "limit 1" or max() or "group by". It also doesn't like trim(). What does work?

Comment: According to this: https://community.teradata.com/t5/Database/Limit-rows/td-p/5238 you would use 'sample 1' or 'top 1' - I've never used Teradata so can't comment further. You could do something similar on the SAS side after the pass-through code returns, but that would be much less efficient.